# Macro to display name of account receiving mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook application that contains multiple email accounts. On one of those accounts, I will occasionally receive emails where I am BCC'd, upon which I want to trigger a macro. I do not wish to trigger this macro when I am BCC'd otherwise, on any of the other accounts.

I am able to trigger a macro when I receive an email, but am unable to distinguish between mails that go to one account versus another.

Comment: Can you post your current/attempted code?

Comment: I agree with Om3r, seeing you code might help us understand your problem.  I have two email addresses.  I have reported both to Outlook using “Add Account” which has created two stores, one per address, named for the email addresses.  I assume that is what you mean by “multiple email accounts”.  I can use a rule or an event to monitor one store.  I can use another rule or another event to monitor the other store.  I do not know any way to monitor both stores with one rule or event.  Your final sentence suggests you are monitoring both stores using one rule or event.

Comment: Possibilities include: (1) We have a terminology problem.  (2) you know how to set up one store to receive emails sent to two separate addresses.  (3) You know how to monitor two stores with one rule or event.  Please describe your problem in enough detail to make clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property. If it is null, you can assume it is the primary account (the first account in the `Namespace.Accounts` collection).